# Nested sql statement in talend (updated)

Tags: sql, talend

I am trying to use nested sql in postgresql tPostgresqlRow_1. 
But I receive an error. 
The following sql runs okay if I run it in PgAdmin. 
But in Talend I receive an error. 
I am getting the max date from one table and updating the column in another table.

```
update "STG_magento_de"."configuration_table"
set created_at=(select MAX(created_at) from "STG_magento_de"."sales_flat_order_test")
where table_name='sales_flat_order_test'
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tPostgresqlRow component expects a Java string containing the SQL statement.

The most likely problem is that you have unescaped quotes in the statement. That works fine in pgAdmin because it is valid.  To pass the same statement from Talend, you'll have to escape all the quotes in the statement itself.  Alternatively, you could try removing the double quotes from the SQL statement.

Remember to enclose the whole thing in quotes, so that it is a proper Java string.

Answer (score 0):

Following sql with escape quotes worked.

```
"update \"STG_magento_de\".\"configuration_table\"
set created_at=(select MAX(created_at) from \"STG_magento_de\".\"sales_flat_order_test\")
where table_name='sales_flat_order_test'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function eliminarComillas (text) returns text AS $$
       select replace(replace(replace($1,'**\"**','&quot;'),'‘','&lsquo;'),'’','&rsquo;');
    $$ language sql;"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!